# Select box options to write to new row in database - MySQL and PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, select

I have a form which currently has the following fields:

```
Name, Size, Template
```

There are two select boxes in this form for the fields **'Size' and 'Template'**. I want the form to insert a new row if a user selects more than one option on the select box.

I have managed to do this for 'Template' but I can not figure out how to use the foreach construct twice so that it also inserts a new row when multiple options are selected from the **Size** field.

Here is my code which works for inserting a new row for multiple 'Template' selected options:

```
$template = $_POST['Template'];
$size = $_POST['Size'];

foreach( $template as $temp ) {

  switch( $temp ) {
 case '1':
   $template;
 break;
 case '2':
   $template;
 break;
 case '3':
   $template;
 break;
  case '4':
   $template;
 break;
 };

 $query = "INSERT INTO tbl (Name,Size,Template) VALUES('$name', '$size', '$temp')";
 }
```

Is there a way to use this foreach statement twice but to run the same query.

For example, I was thinking to do

```
foreach( $size as $newsize) {
switch( $newsize ) {

//cases go here

};
}
```

Comment: if `case '1':` than `$template = "1";` why? if condition and value are same than y r u not using directly? `$template`

Comment: So a name can be matched with multiple sizes and templates? But the number of sizes may be different than the number of templates?

Comment: Note that your present query inserts 4 values into 3 columns so when you say 'it works' you're not really telling the truth, and you're appallingly vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: @Strawberry ID is an auto incremental field.

Comment: Not according to your query

Comment: @Strawberry That was an error I typed out, you can check now the insert definitely works.

Comment: @dimlucas - yes, if you select 3 options on the size select box and 3 options in the template select box then the database should populate in total 9 records .. (i.e: name, size1, template1 | name,size1,template2 | name,size1,template3 and so on)

Answer (score 1):

The `for` loop would be more appropriate for what you've been trying to achieve:

```
for($i=0; $i<count($size); $i++)
{
    for($j=0; $j<count($template); $j++)
    {
        $currentSize = $template[$i];
        $currentTemplate = $template[$j];
        $query = "INSERT INTO tbl (Name, Size, Template) VALUES('$name', '$currentSize', '$currentTemplate')";
    }
}
```

**Warning:** I only wrote the query in the same way you did to demonstrate the rest of the code. The query is actually vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks and you should **definitely** avoid it. Instead write the query like this:

`$query = "INSERT INTO tbl (Name, Size, Template) VALUES(?,?,?)";`

The question marks are place holders. You will need to prepare this statement and then bind `$name`, `$currentTemplate` and `$currentSize` to them before executing. Check [this](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) for more information on prepared statements. Since you need to execute the same query multiple times with different data you have one more reason to use prepared statements. I highly recommend you check Example#3 of the documentation in the link above

Comment: Hi, this code did not work as expected. I selected 3 size options and 3 template options but the sql only executed one template in 3 rows .. and the size field was not written to at all.

Comment: @Zayn Try var_dump($query). You should get 9 queries. If the size is missing then there's something wrong with another part of the code

Comment: It only gives me 3 results unfortunately.. code looks fine elsewhere.

Comment: @Zayn So it only prints you 3 queries? Include these two statements before the first loop: `var_dump($size);` and `var_dump($template);`. Post the results in the comments.

Comment: NULL array(3) { [0]=> string(1) "1" [1]=> string(1) "2" [2]=> string(1) "3" } NULL array(3) { [0]=> string(1) "1" [1]=> string(1) "2" [2]=> string(1) "3" } NULL array(3) { [0]=> string(1) "1" [1]=> string(1) "2" [2]=> string(1) "3" }

Comment: the code above is what outputs.. as you can see only 3 queries

Comment: @Zayn This is the result of which `var_dump` ?